# Custom Shortcut for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am looking for a specific way to open a Chrome extension with a shortcut and then perform a specific action inside.

I already know this page: chrome://extensions/shortcuts, but I can only use it to start my add-on. But when starting or opening the menu of it, I want to press "Take Screenshot". How can I do that? The add-on in the link above, unlike some other add-ons, does not have a wide range of settings.

This is what it looks like and the red rectangle is what I want to shortcut-click:

[Chrome Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay95m.jpg)

[Opened Chrome Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fzsW.jpg)